# Accidentally deleted everything in /boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

So yeah. I was trying to clean up my boot partition and 'rm -r *'. Luckily, I have not turned off my server, so I still have access to things like aptitude and wget. My end goal was/is to update from kernal 4.4 to 4.10. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

More info:
`uname -a: Linux Nephele 4.4.0-64-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 20 11:50:30 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: You'll find copies of the last kernel image you booted in `/` directory with the suffix `.old` not sure if it'll be complete though.

Comment: They unfortunately appear to be (now broken) symlinks to the files I deleted

Comment: You should be able to install newer kernel versions than -64 (mine just installled -71 the other night) and when you reboot you can clean up your existing -64 some how. Nice thing about a server you have weeks to figure it all out.

Comment: This should help... http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/176947/mistakenly-deleted-boot-folder-and-rebooted